# MYSQL reference external field in subquery --- SUM with distinct on other columns

Tags: mysql, select

I can't resolve this problem... hope someone can help me..
I got this query:

```
  SELECT V.ID, ....,

  (SELECT SUM(D.value)
   FROM E 
   LEFT JOIN I   ON E.ID = I.f1 
   LEFT JOIN D   ON I.f2 = D.ID
   WHERE E.ID_ven = V.ID) inc          

   FROM ven V
   WHERE V.ID=....
```

the problem is: 
I have to SUM(D.values) but only on DISTINCT D.ID value.
I tried to subquery with:

```
  SELECT V.ID,...., 

  (SELECT SUM(D.value)    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT D.ID, D.value
      FROM E 
      LEFT JOIN I    ON E.ID = I.f1 
      LEFT JOIN D   ON I.f2 = D.ID
      WHERE E.ID_ven = V.ID) A1   ) inc        
  FROM ven V    WHERE V.ID=....
```

but mysql gives me:
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'V.ID' in 'where clause'

Comment: can u please add the table  description ?

Comment: I extracted this query from a more complex one... so I tried to simplify... what table description do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two double-nested `SELECT` statements, you can use `GROUP BY` to accomplish the "sum of values for each id".

Try the query like this:

```
SELECT V.ID,...., 
    (
        SELECT
            D.ID, SUM(D.value)
        FROM E 
            LEFT JOIN I ON E.ID = I.f1 
            LEFT JOIN D ON I.f2 = D.ID
        WHERE
            E.ID_ven = V.ID
        GROUP BY
            D.ID
    ) inc        
FROM ven V
WHERE V.ID=....
```

By removing the second-nested query, you should be able to access `V.ID` in the sub-query, pending it is an actual column in the `ven` table of course.